# adding a conditional column to a data frame

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop

I have a data frame containing the headlines of news articles (Title) and links(Link)

I want to add a tekker column; basically i have a list of tekkers.
List=["Saham Assurance","Attijariwafa bank"].

Everytime a tekker appears in a headline, the value of the row of this new column will be said tekker:

This is the expected result:

| Title | Link | Tekker |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Saham Assurance: Repli de 6% du chiffre d'affaires à fin septembre | link1 | Saham Assurance |
| Société anonyme : Tour de vis dans le contrôle des conventions réglementées | link2 | NaN |
| Attijariwafa bank : Baisse drastique du coût du risque | link3 | Attijariwafa bank |

I tried this method :

```
df["Tekker"]=np.nan
List=["Saham Assurance","Attijariwafa bank"]
for element in df["title"]:
    i=0
    for tekker in List:
        if tekker  in element:
            df.Tekker[i]=tekker
    i=i+1
```

But it does not work as expected.
I am new to python, so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think this one should work. I assume you expect only one tekker per title:

```
df['Tekker'] = df['Title'].apply(lambda x:t for t in List if t in x)
```